# How to properly call Custom Error Page in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-error-pages

I need to cover some error situations it my app by throwing Custom Error page with some kind of text.

Generally I speak about a situation **when Database is dissabled** (doesn't matter for/because of what kind of reason). In this situation my application are not even initialised, so `protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` can't be used (Response are null, so I can't redirect to something).

I tried to use CustomError:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" >
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/DefaultError" />
   </customErrors>
   ...
</system.web>
```

and

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult DefaultError()
{
    return View();
}
```

But because custom error screen didn't showed up, I assume that I missed something. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong trying to call CustomError in MVC or what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only error code you are capturing is 500, which is internal server error while processing the request. There may be another error code (e.g. 400, 403,  etc), and in that case the response will not redirect to "/Error/DefaultError". There are response codes related to client side and server side errors.

You can add defaultRedirect in customErrors tag like this:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/DefaultError" />
   </customErrors>
   ...
</system.web>
```

This will redirect your response to Index method of Error controller, in which you can show a default error.

Read this link [Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for more detail about HTML status codes.